# Use different serializer for request and reply

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I can use different serializers for `POST` / `GET` requests as follows:

```
class CommandViewSet(DynamicModelViewSet):
    queryset = Command.objects.all()
    serializer_class_post = CommandSerializerPost
    serializer_class_get = CommandSerializerGet
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return self.serializer_class_post
        elif self.request.method == 'GET':
            return self.serializer_class_get
```

Now I would like to use a different serializer for the *request* and the *reply* of a `POST` request. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 10):

You can override serializer's `to_representation()` method for this:

```
class CommandSerializerPost(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # yur code here

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        serializer = CommandSerializerGet(instance)
        return serializer.data
```

**UPD**

In above code, `CommandSerializerPost` will **always** returns the output of `CommandSerializerGet`, irrespective of the **`request.method`**. So it should be like this if you need to change respnse only for `GET` request:

```
class CommandSerializerPost(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        if self.context['request'].method == 'GET':
            serializer = CommandSerializerGet(instance)
            return serializer.data
        return super().to_representation(instance)
```

Comment: @dangonfast yes you can remove `get_serializer_class` method from your view. `to_representation` will automatically using for get requests also. I only can find this link: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#baseserializer

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Thanks for edit, but I suppose OP want to change output for all types of request even POST. So I leave both variants.

Comment: Again typo, Change //In above code, **CommandSerializerPost** will always returns the output of **CommandSerializerPost** // to  //In above code, **CommandSerializerPost** will always returns the output of **CommandSerializerGet** //

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge argh! Thanks again:)

Comment: and If the user needs to access `CommandSerializerGet` all the time, he doesn't want to override `to_representation()` method :)

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge in some cases you need to post one fields and receive another. I think this is that case.

Answer (score 5):

You can receive data by MySerializer1 and response to request by MySerializer2

```
Class MyView(APIView):
    def post(selft, request):
        serializer1 = MySerializer1(request.data)
        # other codes
        serializer2 = MySerializer2(changedData)
        return response(serializer2.data)
```